# add column only if table not exists

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I am creating a column in a table:

```
client.query("ALTER TABLE mytable ADD theField text", function(err, result)  {
```

Now, I want to perform a test ,so if the column already exists , don't execute the statement.

I tried:

```
client.query("ALTER TABLE mytable IF NOT EXISTS ADD theField text", function(err, result)  {


client.query("ALTER TABLE mytable  ADD theField text IF NOT EXISTS", function(err, result)  {


client.query("ALTER TABLE mytable  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable ADD theField text)", function(err, result)  {
```

but all giving syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code `ALTER TABLE mytable IF NOT EXISTS ADD theField text` will add column `thefield`. if you want it to be called precisely `theField` you should run this: `ALTER TABLE mytable IF NOT EXISTS ADD "theField" text`
This is why I check if column exists ignoring the case: `lower(blaH-BLah)` equal to `lower(blAh-bLAh)`, cos it makes `blah-bLah` value. This is why your query should be:

```
client.query("do"+

   " $$"+
    "begin"+
     " if (select count(*) from information_schema.columns" +
      "     where table_schema = 'public' " +
       "    and table_name = 'mytable' "+
       "    and lower(column_name) = lower('theField')) < 1 " + 
      " then "+
      "ALTER TABLE mytable ADD \"theField\" text;"+
      "end if;"+
    "end;"+
    "$$"+
    ";", function(err, result)  {
```

Comment: What is `myschema`?

Comment: schema name where you have your table

Comment: if you did not specify it anywhere - should be public

Comment: :I am receiving : `There was an error :  { error: missing "THEN" at end of SQL expression` . I uploaded [here](http://paste.ofcode.org/DMSj3nDCFb6GZDCVTUh8kU).Note,that i used `' '` outside in order to use the `theField`.and I  ommited the `lower(..)`.

Comment: you cant ommit column part if you want to check if column exists. also you cant use `"`' for text value, dbl quotas are used for object names. in this case `theField` etc is not a name - it is part of where clause

Comment: I want to keep the `theField` with lower and uppercase letters.Is the `<1` you updated does that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114936/discussion-between-vao-tsun-and-george).

Comment: :Hello ! I opened a similar thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026294/do-nothing-if-table-doesnt-exist) if you are interested.Thanks!