# do nothing if table doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I want to execute a query only if the table exists.

If the table doesn't exist do nothing.

Hence, I want to check if table exists then check if there is some data in the table and if there are some ,select them.

I want this `/client.query( "SELECT * FROM mytable", function(err,res) {`

So , I tried something like :

```
client.query("do"+
                    " $$"+
                    "begin"+
                    " if (select count(*) from information_schema.columns" +
                    "     where table_schema = 'public' " +
                    "    and table_name = 'mytable' )"+
                    " then "+
                    "DO NOTHING;"+
                    "else "+
                    "SELECT * FROM mytable;" +
                    "end if;"+
                    "end;"+
                    "$$"+
                    ";", function(err, res)  {
```

I am not sure about the use of `DO NOTHING` , and right now I am receiving `error: syntax error at or near "NOTHING"`

If I use NOT:

```
 client.query("do"+
                        " $$"+
                        "begin"+
                        " if NOT (select count(*) = 0  from information_schema.columns" +
                        "     where table_schema = 'public' " +
                        "    and table_name = 'mytable' )"+
                        " then "+
                        "SELECT * FROM mytable;" +
                        "end if;"+
                        "end;"+
                        "$$"+
                        ";", function(err, res)  {
```

Ιt works when the table is empty ,but when I fill the table where it should do `select * from table` it throws `error: query has no destination for result data`

Comment: what do you want to the data from mytable if it exists?..

Comment: @VaoTsun:When I click ( onto my program ) the field `CheckMe` for example, it shows me all the fields from mytable.This happens when it is full.When the table is empty , I am getting an error ( because it is empty ).So , I want to avoid this.

Comment: so you want to check if table exists then check if there is some data in the table and if there are some you want to select it?.. all in one procedure - right?..

Comment: @VaoTsun:Yes ,that;s it!

Comment: then update your question so other people would understand your needs

Comment: what is the field name you use as result for `CheckMe`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun:CheckMe is just a button I press to see the results of the query.

Answer (score 0):

concider using [callback](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#method-query-simple) instead, smth like this:

```
client.query("select count(*) c from information_schema.columns" +
  "     where table_schema = 'public' " +
  "    and table_name = 'mytable'", function(err, res)  {
      if (parseInt(res.rows[0].c) > 0 ) {
        client.query("select * from PUBLIC.mytable", function(err1, res1)  {
          if (res1.rows.length == 0 ) {
            console.log('table is empty');
            } else{
          console.log(res1.rows[0].some_field);
          }
        });
      }
});
```

Comment: :When the table is empty and I visit for the first time it just hangs ,withut errors.When the table is full , it works ok! ( you missed a `});` for the outer query )

Comment: :For some reason it doesn't return the `table is empty`.It hangs

Comment: run without data and show what you see here: `console.log('no data',res.rows);`

Comment: If I run the console.log at the second query as you have it , it still hangs without showing anythng.If I put the `console.log(no data` to the first query ,it returns `no data [ anonymous { c: '0' } ]`

Comment: [Here](http://paste.ofcode.org/sJK4qj8CVrBjufisDUQW4U) is the result of printing `docs` in the first query.

Comment: :No,still the same.I must say though that the approach with using `if NOT` like Abelisto said , it worked when the table was empty but when it was full it gave me `error: query has no destination for result data`.But I don't know how to return this!

Comment: `error: relation "public.mytable" does not exist`.Any ideas?This happens if I ommit the `if (parseInt(res.rows[0].c) > 0 ) {`